# How to modify the BIOS boot options to USB-HDD in C#?

Tags: c#, usb, bios

I want to know if I can do it in C# or other languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no universal way to do this because BIOS configurations vary from vendor to vendor.** The mapping of various CMOS memory locations is unique to the motherboard, BIOS, and BIOS revision. You'll have to find out this information from your particular vendor, and your app won't be very portable.

Plus, even once you get past this hurdle, Windows won't allow you to access the BIOS (or otherwise do port I/O) from a user-mode application. You'll have to write a kernel mode driver to be able to do this. And of course, you cannot write kernel mode drivers in C# because the runtime executes in user mode. You'll have to write something like this in C.

Comment: Just as a brief side note... with a UEFI BIOS, changing boot order should be easier to do in a portable fashion. However, yes, you will still need at least a little bit of kernel mode to actually change it.

Comment: Hardly any consumer-based motherboards use an UEFI-based BIOS. About the only place you'll find that now is on the Macintosh and Itanium-based machines. Maybe eventually the industry will make the switch, but you can hardly count on it being the case presently.

Comment: That's true, few consumer BIOSs can boot an EFI OS presently, although from my standpoint, many manufacturers only option right now for new platforms is a UEFI solution. I've also seen a number of boards that have UEFI under the hood but not be capable of booting an EFI OS, so I don't think it will be too long now before the industry switches over. I'll certainly be glad for the switch when it happens, though!